# Upgrading to JRE7 throws java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror

My product was running with **JRE 6.31** without any problems. Now I am trying to set it to work with JRE 7, but when I run it on a Linux machine I am getting:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.awt.X11FontManager
```

When calling to `java.awt.Font.canDisplayUpTo()`. Is this case looks familiar to someone?

Comment: This comes from an incomplete installation of Java environnement. Is the *DejaVu* font correctly installed? How did you install JRE7?

Comment: post the full stack trace?

Comment: Alban, Actually I didn't install the JRE7. I am using it through the extracted package.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your Linux machine either does not have X11 installed, or has not a X display available.

If yours is a server application, try to force the headless rendering by using the command line switch:

```
-Djava.awt.headless=true
```

**EDIT:**

Also, users reported that on Linux systems, both Oracle JDK 1.7 and OpenJDK 1.7 require the dejavu font installed.